# Get Saved Credit/Debit Card Details in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, payment-methods, credit-card

How can I get already saved credit/debit card details to use in my custom module from checkout page before place order.

Comment: you need to check vault functionality in Magento.

Comment: what is your exact requirement.

Comment: @Yogita : Have able to achive your requirment. Actually I also want that. I have saved card details in db but now I want to use that card details for order place.

Answer (score 0):

**No, you can retrieve only last four credit card digits from an order in Magento's flow for security reasons.**

---

use event (`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`) and  observer to get order details

```
//***if orderid=1001;***

$orderId=1001;
$order = $this->order->load($orderId);
$expmonth=$order->getPayment()->getCcExpMonth();    //get expirymonth* 
$expyear=$order->getPayment()->getCcExpYear();      //get expiryyear*
$cclast4=$order->getPayment()->getCcLast4();        //get expiry last four digit from card*
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load a customer's saved card info from their `customerId` by using the following:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Mondule\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Vault\Api\PaymentTokenManagementInterface;

class Connector extends Action
{
  protected $customerRepositoryFactory;
  protected $paymentTokenManagement;

  public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $pageFactory,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    PaymentTokenManagementInterface $paymentTokenManagement,
    array $data = []
  ) {
    $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->paymentTokenManagement = $paymentTokenManagement;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    // CUSTOMER
    $customerId = '1';
    $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);

    // Get Saved CC
    $cardList = $this->paymentTokenManagement->getListByCustomerId($customerId);

    foreach($cardList as $card) {
      if ($card->getIsActive()) {
        echo $card->getData();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I should note that this is just a snippet from our implementation. Without seeing any of your code, you may need to alter it some depending on your application.